# How can I create multiple progress bars using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, progress-bar

I've been playing around with the code below and using it to create a progress bar that responds to a certain type of data input. The data I'm using comes in the form of an array but I've noticed that the code only creates one progress bar.

How could I embed this within my `for` loop so that it creates a separate *progress bar* for each item in the array?

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 2000);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width=width + 10; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = ((100 - width)/10) + ' mins';
    }
  }
}

move();
```

```css
#myProgress {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    horizontal-align: center;
}

#myBar {
    width: 0%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the link to what I'm working on: [My Workspace](https://playcode.io/109917?tabs=console&script.js&output)

**Side Note:** I've been trying to get the progress bar to be centered on the page with a `margin: 200px` on either side. The `margin` attribute in my CSS doesn't seem to be doing this and only applying the `margin` to the left but not to the right - *where am I going wrong with this*?

Comment: This will fix your styling issue:
#myProgress {
    width: calc(100% - 400px);
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

Comment: `id`s are only allowed for 1 element if you want multiple equal elements use `class`es

Comment: @nlingam please try the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<html>
<style>
 #myProgress {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

 .myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
 }
 </style>
<body>



<div id="myProgress">

</div>

 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var progressbars="";
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i <=10; i++) { 
  progressbars+="<div class='myBar' style='width:"+i+"%'"
   + " id='myBar"+i+"px'"
   +">"+i+"%"+"</div><br/>";
  }

  $("#myProgress").html(progressbars);
  });

   </script>
   </html>
```

**Using Javascript Only**
Just replace previous script with this

```
 <script>
  window.onload=function(){
 var progressbars="";
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i <=10; i++) { 
    progressbars+="<div class='myBar' style='width:"+i+"%'"
   + " id='myBar"+i+"px'"
    +">"+i+"%"+"</div><br/>";
  }
   document.getElementById("myProgress").innerHTML=progressbars;


 }
```

This will generate 
[image]

Comment: is there a way I can do this without using jquery?

Comment: that works fine for me on its own, but the only issue I'm having is executing a function within that. I have a function called move() which moves the js progress bar and counts down from 10 whilst it does this. Even though I've created different progress bars now, I can't get the function to work for each one.

Comment: can you please show me the code where your move function is written

Comment: if you check here https://playcode.io/109917?tabs=console&script.js&output

Comment: @nlingam that code is already setting unique id to each progress using "id='myBar"+i" why dont you use this id?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have included bootstrap 4
In that case you can create progress bars with Bootstrap

```
var progressbars="";
  for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) { 
    progressbars+='<div class="progress">'
        +'<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: '+i+'%" aria-valuenow="'+i+'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">'+i+'%</div>'
    +'</div>';
  }
   document.querySelector(".feefo").innerHTML=progressbars;
```

And it looks a lot nicer :)